# Lipschitz map of the circle onto a triangle

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f$ is (Euclidean) $L-$biLipchitz mapping of the unit circle onto a triangle $\Delta(A,B,C)$. Can we find a $10000 L$ bi-lipchitz extension of $f$ onto the whole plane.

Answer (score 7):

See http://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.3443.pdf: The results of the paper are for maps $R\to R^2$, but, as the author says in the introduction, conjugating with Moebius transformations, one gets bi-Lipschitz extension for maps of the unit circle (with controlled increase in the BL-constant). Now, you would have to do some computations yourself to see if the constant you get is $<10^4$.

Edit: Here is the full statement of [Kovalev's theorem](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.3443.pdf) I linked above, since it is very nice and deserves to be better known:

Let $f: {\mathbb R}\to {\mathbb R}^2$ be an $L$-bi-Lipschitz embedding. Then $f$ extends to an $2000L$-bi-Lipschitz embedding ${\mathbb R}^2\to {\mathbb R}^2$.

Unfortunately, the result is not quite what you need.

Comment: Then you obtain $L^9$ growth of bi-Lipschitz constant. 